# Convert RFC date to short date mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to convert an RFC 822 formatted date into the short date format of mm/dd/yyyy using VB.net. I have a  web application that I cannot change the source code for.  The web application allows an RSS feed to be sorted by month and year.

Would appreciate any advice or assistance.

Comment: How do you expect to change the application without being able to change the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Date.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) to convert the string to a Date value, then use Date.ToString with a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to set the format the way you want it.